# How to import the Python async module from a worker thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, signals, gitpython

I'm using the [GitPython package](http://gitorious.org/git-python) to access a Git repository from Python. This pulls in the [async package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/async/0.6.1). In `async/__init__.py`, the following happens:

```
def _init_signals():
    """Assure we shutdown our threads correctly when being interrupted"""
    import signal
    # ...
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, thread_interrupt_handler)

_init_signals()
```

This works fine if everything is in the main thread. However, when the first import of `git` (and thus `async`) happens on another thread, things go boom:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Since all this runs inside the Django framework, I have no control over threading.

One workaround I've found is to put `import async` into `settings.py`, which is (apparently) imported on the main thread. However, this needs to be done on a per-install basis, so it's not very nice towards users of my Django app.

I tried catching the exception, but an import that raised an exception does not fully complete, so the next `import async` will fail as well.

Can you think of any halfway decent method to work/hack around this problem?

---

Update: I noticed that Apache's mod_wsgi is smart enough to ignore the `signal` call:

```
[Tue Sep 07 19:53:11 2010] [warn] mod_wsgi (pid=28595): Callback registration for signal 2 ignored.
```

The problem remains with the Django development server, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pull the latest async code from git, I suspect this will be fixed for you and is called out as a non-fatal error in the [patch](http://gitorious.org/git-python/async/commit/5992bb6c85973ed81c54c71fef42e2413cd29e88)

Comment: Ha, brilliant, thanks! It may be a non-fatal error, but if the `ValueError` leaves the module, the `import` fails so the module cannot be used.